# go lang + snmp in lool (error connection processing)

Tags: loops, go, snmp

I do a server on golnag and I need to do a SNMP command to many devices, some of this devices could not have connections( or lost it temporary)
And I want message " no connection" or "Error"  and next continue the runing of programm

Ubuntu 18.04 // go 1.8 // go SNMP from https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    g "github.com/soniah/gosnmp"
)

func main() {
    g.Default.Target = string("192.168.10.1")
    err := g.Default.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Connect() err: %v", err)
        fmt.Println("Fail connection") // want this message in this case  !!!!!
    }
    defer g.Default.Conn.Close()

    oids := []string{"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0"} 
    result, err2 := g.Default.Get(oids)  
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Get() err: %v", err2)
        fmt.Println("Error read OID") // want this message in this case !!!!!
    }

    for i, variable := range result.Variables {
        fmt.Printf("%d: oid: %s ", i, variable.Name)

        switch variable.Type {
        case g.OctetString:
            fmt.Printf("string: %s\n", string(variable.Value.([]byte)))
        default:
            fmt.Printf("number: %d\n", g.ToBigInt(variable.Value))
        }
    }
}
```

I receive this result if no connection, and break the runing of pogramm

```
2019/05/19 15:11:33 Get() err: Request timeout (after 3 retries)
exit status 1
```

I want something like this

```
"Fail connection"   or  "Error read OID"
```

And next, I want to continue the runing of programm

Comment: Just change the log.Fatalf string param, like ```log.Fatalf("Error read OID")```. Or if you need this error to be written in the std.Output, replace log.Fatalf to log.Printf

Comment: @Sergey Narozhnyy, ?   like this:                                                                                                               
    if err != nil {
        log.Prinf("ERROR")
    }

Comment: Not exactly, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have unreachable code in lines where you've left comments.

Just use correct string value for log.Fatalf:

```golang
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Fail connection, error: %v", err)
}
```

or if you don't want to exit:

```golang
if err != nil {
  log.Printf("Fail connection, error: %v", err)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Sergey Narozhnyy@ thanks! And the big mistake is block with processing of "result.Variables". There is no "result" if i don't have the connection

Comment: Please do not write comments in answers. Take [Tour] again if you need a refresher on how SO works. Thanks